# PHP Header Location Variable Redirection and output at home page

Tags: php, forms, post, header

I have a page with `form` that makes a POST request and has one input where I put surname.

After submitting the form
I want to get from `SESSION['surname']` submitted variable
and after that back to home_page via `header("Location...")`.

I would like a last variable name to appear on the main page under the form.
How to do it?

can anyone guide on this?

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: the value from the surname-field in the form will be in $POST['surname'] and not in $SESSION['surname']. You could then store that variable in $SESSION['surname'] to access it later.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that;
Main Page with the form:

```
<form action="src/session.php" method="POST">
<div>SESSION</div>
<div>
  <label for="surname">Surname</label>
  <input name="surname">
</div>
<button type="submit" name="approve" value="approval">Send</button>
</form>
```

in src/session.php:

```
<?php
if($_POST['approve']) {
    $_SESSION['surname'] = urlencode($_REQUEST['surname']);
    $var = $_SESSION['surname'];
}

header("Location: https://....");   #here should be the home page with the form and after redirect i want to see exactly same form but with $var underneath it
?>
```